# Disabling JButton Inside JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

I am trying to make a application where it will retrieve some data from database and will fill the data into JTable. In the table there will be 2 buttons which will update a status field of my database column (that is custom object of my model for that row) .

After doing so ,the first button will get disabled and the second button will get enabled for that row/object.

I tried to use JButtonColumn as a test but the problem is when i click 2 different button,the other buttons in between get disabled also. This is what i have tried so far:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class JavaApplication1 extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTable table;
    private MyTableModel myModel = new MyTableModel();

    public JavaApplication1() {


        table = new JTable(myModel);
        addTableDatas();
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);
        ButtonColumn buttonColumn = new ButtonColumn(table, delete, 3);
        buttonColumn.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaApplication1 frame = new JavaApplication1();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addTableDatas() {
        Vector<String> columnNameS = new Vector<String>();
        columnNameS.add("Date");
        columnNameS.add("String");
        columnNameS.add("Decimal");
        columnNameS.add("Remove");
        myModel.setColumnNames(columnNameS);

        Vector<Object> row1 = new Vector<Object>();
        row1.add(new Date());
        row1.add("A");
        row1.add(new Double(5.1));
        row1.add("Remove");
        myModel.addRow(row1);

        row1 = new Vector<Object>();
        row1.add(new Date());
        row1.add("B");
        row1.add(new Double(6.2));
        row1.add("Remove");
        myModel.addRow(row1);

        row1 = new Vector<Object>();
        row1.add(new Date());
        row1.add("B");
        row1.add(new Double(8.4));
        row1.add("Remove");
        myModel.addRow(row1);

        row1 = new Vector<Object>();
        row1.add(new Date());
        row1.add("B");
        row1.add(new Double(5.1));
        row1.add("Remove");
        myModel.addRow(row1);

        row1 = new Vector<Object>();
        row1.add(new Date());
        row1.add("B");
        row1.add(new Double(6.2));
        row1.add("Remove");
        myModel.addRow(row1);
    }

    private class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private Vector<Vector<Object>> data;
        private Vector<String> colNames;
        private boolean[] _columnsVisible = {true, true, true, true};

        public MyTableModel() {
            this.colNames = new Vector<String>();
            this.data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
        }

        public MyTableModel(Vector<String> colnames) {
            this.colNames = colnames;
            this.data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
        }

        public void resetTable() {
            this.colNames.removeAllElements();
            this.data.removeAllElements();
        }

        public void setColumnNames(Vector<String> colNames) {
            this.colNames = colNames;
            this.fireTableStructureChanged();
        }

        public void addRow(Vector<Object> data) {
            this.data.add(data);
            this.fireTableRowsInserted(data.size() - 1, data.size() - 1);
        }

        public void removeRowAt(int row) {
            this.data.removeElementAt(row);
            this.fireTableRowsDeleted(row - 1, data.size() - 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return this.colNames.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int colNum) {
            switch (colNum) {
                case 0:
                    return Date.class;
                case 2:
                    return Double.class;
                default:
                    return String.class;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int colNum) {
            switch (colNum) {
                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int colNum) {
            return this.colNames.get(colNum);
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return this.data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            Vector<Object> value = this.data.get(row);
            return value.get(col);
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object newVal, int row, int col) {
            Vector<Object> aRow = data.elementAt(row);
            aRow.remove(col);
            aRow.insertElementAt(newVal, col);
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        }

        public void setColumnVisible(int index, boolean visible) {
            this._columnsVisible[index] = visible;
            this.fireTableStructureChanged();
        }
    }
    //
    private Action delete = new AbstractAction() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            JTable table = (JTable) e.getSource();
            int modelRow = Integer.valueOf(e.getActionCommand());
            //(MyTableModel) table.getModel()).removeRowAt(modelRow);

            //table.clearSelection();
        }
    };
}
```

JButtonColumn.Java :

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class ButtonColumn extends AbstractCellEditor
    implements TableCellRenderer, TableCellEditor, ActionListener,MouseListener
{
    private JTable table;
    private Action action;
    private int mnemonic;
    private Border originalBorder;
    private Border focusBorder;

    private JButton renderButton;
    private JButton editButton;
    private Object editorValue;
    private boolean isButtonColumnEditor;

    public ButtonColumn(JTable table, Action action, int column)
    {
        this.table = table;
        this.action = action;

        renderButton = new JButton();
        editButton = new JButton();
        editButton.setFocusPainted( false );
        editButton.addActionListener( this );
        originalBorder = editButton.getBorder();
        setFocusBorder( new LineBorder(Color.BLUE) );

        TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
        columnModel.getColumn(column).setCellRenderer( this );
        columnModel.getColumn(column).setCellEditor( this );
        table.addMouseListener( this );
    }


    public Border getFocusBorder()
    {
        return focusBorder;
    }

    public void setFocusBorder(Border focusBorder)
    {
        this.focusBorder = focusBorder;
        editButton.setBorder( focusBorder );
    }

    public int getMnemonic()
    {
        return mnemonic;
    }

    public void setMnemonic(int mnemonic)
    {
        this.mnemonic = mnemonic;
        renderButton.setMnemonic(mnemonic);
        editButton.setMnemonic(mnemonic);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, 
                Object value,boolean isSelected, int row, int column)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            editButton.setText( "" );
            editButton.setIcon( null );
        }
        else if (value instanceof Icon)
        {
            editButton.setText( "" );
            editButton.setIcon( (Icon)value );
        }
        else
        {
            editButton.setText( value.toString() );
            editButton.setIcon( null );
        }

        this.editorValue = value;
        return editButton;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue()
    {
        return editorValue;
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, 
                      boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        if (isSelected)
        {
            renderButton.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            renderButton.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        }
        else
        {                

renderButton.setForeground(table.getForeground());                  

               renderButton.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
        }

        if (hasFocus)
        {
            renderButton.setBorder( focusBorder );
        }
        else
        {
            renderButton.setBorder( originalBorder );
        }


        if (value == null)
        {
            renderButton.setText( "" );
            renderButton.setIcon( null );
        }
        else if (value instanceof Icon)
        {
            renderButton.setText( "" );
            renderButton.setIcon( (Icon)value );
        }
        else
        {
            renderButton.setText( value.toString() );
            renderButton.setIcon( null );
        }

        return renderButton;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        int row = table.convertRowIndexToModel( table.getEditingRow() );
        fireEditingStopped();

        //  Invoke the Action

        ActionEvent event = new ActionEvent(
            table,
            ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED,
            "" + row);
        action.actionPerformed(event);
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (table.isEditing()
        &&  table.getCellEditor() == this)
            isButtonColumnEditor = true;
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (isButtonColumnEditor
        &&  table.isEditing())
            table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();

                    //Disabling the button here
                    renderButton.setEnabled(false); 

                    System.out.println("ROW CLICKED");

        isButtonColumnEditor = false;
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

Comment: where you enable/disable buttons? You use the reference to the button to disable a specific button?

Comment: Sorry for not adding the other class. I have edited my post where i added the JButtonColumn class. I did disabled the button inside the MouseReleased() function.

Answer (score 0):

The class is `ButtonColumn`. See: [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/).

You can't just disable the button in the editor. That button is shared by all rows in the table. The is the way all renderers/editor work.

You will need to customize the renderer/editor code. That is you will need to override the `isCellEditable(...)` of your TableModel to determine when the cell is editable based on the data in your table:

1. If you have NOT updated the database status, then button1 will be editable and button2 will not be editable
2. If you have updated the database status, then button1 will NOT be editable and button2 will be editable

Then you can customize the disable state of the button in the renderer:

1. if the cell is editable, the button state is enabled
2. if the cell is not editable, the button state is disabled.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information on renderers/editors and the isCellEditable() method.